# Is $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k = 1}^\infty \frac{(1-\epsilon(n))^k}{k}$ Finite When $\epsilon(n) \rightarrow 0$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Consider the sum
$$
\sum_{k = 1}^\infty \frac{(1-\epsilon)^k}{k}
$$
with $\epsilon \in (0,1)$. One can show (by the ratio test, for example) that the sum is finite.

Now, let $\epsilon(n)$ tend to $0$ as $n$ tends toward infinity. What can be said about the limit
$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k = 1}^\infty \frac{(1-\epsilon(n))^k}{k}?
$$
Does it exist? Is it finite?

The only approach I know would be to find a closed form for
$$
f(n) = \sum_{k = 1}^\infty \frac{(1-\epsilon(n))^k}{k}
$$
in terms of $\epsilon(n)$ and inspect the limit, but I cannot make any progress on this front.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also made this much more complicated than it is...

Recall the [Taylor series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) of $\ln(1-x)$ at $0$:
$$
\ln(1-x)=-\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{x^k}{k}\qquad \forall -1\leq x<1.
$$

Hence
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{(1-\epsilon(n))^k}{k}=-\ln \epsilon(n)\longrightarrow +\infty.
$$

Answer (score 3):

For the closed form, note that $\dfrac{1}{1-t}=1+t+t^2+t^3+\cdots$ and integrate term by term from $0$ to $x$, where $x$ in your case is $1-\epsilon$.